# Origin of the use of exclamation marks to attach modifiers to distinguish different versions of characters

Tags: history-of, terminology, fandom

In online fandom communities, I've noticed a not-uncommon convention (though I'm not sure it's the prevailing convention; more common seems to be a simple space or a hyphen) of using an exclamation mark to attach modifiers to distinguish between different versions of a character from different adaptations of a work.

For instance, *A Song of Ice and Fire*/*Game of Thrones* fans might talk about the differences between the characters of Book!Tyrion and Show!Tyrion, if they wish to refer to the differences in his character between adaptations.

What is the origin of this? Does it have something to do with Usenet and bang paths? It's quite a tricky thing to Google for.

Comment: examples...examples...most of here haven't  the  foggiest what you are asking.

Comment: I keep reading it as "not."  So, the book without Tyrion would be...  very different, at least in some storylines.

Comment: https://www.angelfire.com/falcon/moonbeam/terms.html#! doesn't explain wherefrom.

Comment: Wikipedia has an uncited statement that it may have originated with TMNT figures being married as "Hockey Player! Raphael" and the like, although that convention doesn't seem to have actually been used on the boxes.

Comment: In UNIX scripting, the exclamation point is used for telling the operating system which application to use for running the script. -- relevant?

Comment: I think it is a programming thing, but possibly from spreadsheets - eg you use `Sheet1!A1` to refer to cell A1 on sheet Sheet1. I think Microsoft Access has a similar usage.

Comment: [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CharacterizationTags) also defines these but doesn't have a history, but it does suggest they might derive from the old convention of [bang paths](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bang-path.html), presumably by way of Usenet fandoms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have better luck Googling the term "exclamation compounds" which is the term at least one linguist uses

https://allthingslinguistic.com/post/46453848763/exclamationcompounds
The linguist is Gretchen McCulloch, author of "Because Internet" (which also discusses "Exclamation Compounds")

Quote from the link above:

> If you spend time on certain linguistically innovative corners of the
> internet, you may have noticed a new way of putting words together,
> with as the title suggests, exclamation marks. I’m going to call this
> construction exclamation!compounds, for obvious reasons.
>
> History of Exclamation!compounds
>
> My first memorable encounter with exclamation!compounds came from The
> Lizzie Bennet Diaries, a webseries in which many characters act out
> other characters in costume theatre. When a character is acting
> another, the resulting character-within-a-character is referred to by
> exclamation!compounding maincharacter!actedcharacter. For example,
> Jane playing Darcy is Jane!Darcy, and likewise for Lizzie!MrsBennet
> and Charlotte!MrBennet.

[Fanlore](https://fanlore.org/wiki/%21) traces this usage back to 1997.

> The adj!noun format is purported to have started in X-Files fandom.
> Good examples for this are Wombat's Spotter's Guide to the Common
> Krycek and the accompanying Spotter's Guide to the Common Mulder where
> several Krycek sub-species such as Bad to the Bone!Krycek, Bad but
> Lovin'!Krycek, Hot'n'dirty!Krycek or Misunderstood!Krycek and Mulder
> sub-subspecies such as Angst!Mulder, Basketcase!Mulder,
> HappySlut!Mulder, Sensitive!Mulder and WellAdjusted!Mulder are
> described. The first usage was Action!Mulder, referring to canon
> scenes where Mulder suddenly went all actiony (instead of talky),
> followed by Saint!Scully. Eventually they lost the initial capitals
> and the canon connections; by the time it hit other fandoms, it was
> being used to describe fannish things.[4]
>
> Another X-Files mention, this one from the FAQ for OBSSE in 1997:
> "'Where did "!Scully" come from?' This is a sort of shorthand for
> describing our favorite characters, depending on what they were doing
> (such as Action!Scully or Kickass!Scully). It's sort of a designation
> for hypothetical action figures. For more information on some of the
> Order's favorite hypothetical action figures, see the October 1997
> OBSSE Newsletter Poll." [5][6]

Comment: This is pretty close to a link-only answer, which are discouraged, as links break.  A short summary of the history (but longer than "first use in 1997") would improve this answer a lot.

Comment: Upvoted but not yet accepted. Ping me once you've edited in a short summary of the link and I'll accept it :)

Comment: The fanlore page in particular has a lot of useful historical information, such as it most likely originally coming from the X-Files community, being used to refer to different ways certain characters were sometimes written/sometimes behaved.

Comment: @Muzer: Edits made.